# ¿Cómo realizar un rollback?

Tags: c#

¿Cómo implemento un rollback dentro de mi `Insert`?

```
 DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Confirme que desea guardar", "Confirmar", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
        try
        {


            string query = "insert into PesoDespacho values (@FolioPallet, @peso, @Fecha, @NinstructivoT, @Nnave)";
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexionc.ObtenerConexion());
               foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
               {

                   cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FolioPallet", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Foliopalet"].Value));
                   //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Peso", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Peso"].Value));
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Peso", Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Peso"].Value));

                   //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Fecha"].Value));
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Fecha"].Value));

            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Hora"].Value));
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NinstructivoT", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Ninstructivo"].Value));
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nnave", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Nnave"].Value));
                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


               }
               conexionc.ObtenerConexion().Close();
               MessageBox.Show("Guardado con Exito. ", "Guardado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
               correo();
               operaciones.numerodecontenedor siguiente = new operaciones.numerodecontenedor();
               this.Close();
               siguiente.Show();

        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
                conexionc.ObtenerConexion().Close();
                MessageBox.Show("No se han guardado los datos-verifique la conexión a Internet", "Error - por favor guarde los datos en excel", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                exportar(dataGridView1);
                correoerror();


        }

                    }
                    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Operacion cancelada.");
                    }
```

Tengo ese método, lo que hace es recorrer un datagrid e ir guardando los registros en una base de datos. El problema que tengo es que cuando se produce un error al insertar la fila 10 o cualquiera, guarda hasta la fila 9. Lo que necesito es que si por alguna razón arroja un error no guarde nada.

Answer (score 6):

Para hacer eso tienes que usar [Transacciones](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction?view=netframework-4.7.2) de SQL y cuando termines de tratar todas las lineas ejecutar el `Commit` de la siguiente manera:

```
string query = "insert into PesoDespacho values (@FolioPallet, @peso, @Fecha, @NinstructivoT, @Nnave)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexionc.ObtenerConexion());
//Creamos la transacción a fuera para poder cogerla en el Catch
SqlTransaction trans = conexionc.ObtenerConexion().BeginTransaction("NombreTransaccion"); 
cmd.Transaction = trans;
try
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FolioPallet", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Foliopalet"].Value));
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Peso", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Peso"].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Peso", Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Peso"].Value));

        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Fecha"].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Fecha"].Value));

        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Hora"].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NinstructivoT", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Ninstructivo"].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nnave", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Nnave"].Value));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    trans.Commit(); //Guardamos los valores a la base de datos
    conexionc.ObtenerConexion().Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Guardado con Éxito. ", "Guardado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    correo();
    operaciones.numerodecontenedor siguiente = new operaciones.numerodecontenedor();
    this.Close();
    siguiente.Show();

}
catch (Exception f)
{
    trans.Rollback(); //Hacemos rollback para que no guarde nada
    conexionc.ObtenerConexion().Close();
    MessageBox.Show("No se han guardado los datos-verifique la conexión a internet", "Error - por favor guarde los datos en excel", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    exportar(dataGridView1);
    correoerror();
}
```

Comment: a que se refiere en "NombreTransaccion"?

Comment: @sebastianbizamainostroza Es un nombre para la transacción, puedes ponerlo o puedes crear una sin nombre poniendo `.BeginTransaction()`

Answer (score 3):

La forma mas simple seria usando el `TransactioScope`

[Implementar una transacción implícita mediante el ámbito de la transacción](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope)

ya que defines un ambito en el cual se trabaja las operaciones de forma transaccional

Pero no va aplicar si usas esa forma de obtener la conexion `conexionc.ObtenerConexion()`

Deberias simplemente recuperar el `connection string` y definir el `SqlConnection` dentro de `scope` como lo muestro aqui

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Confirme que desea guardar", "Confirmar", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Operacion cancelada.");
    return;
}


if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    try
    {

        using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            var connString = conexionc.ConnectionString;

            using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                string query = "insert into PesoDespacho values (@FolioPallet, @peso, @Fecha, @NinstructivoT, @Nnave)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FolioPallet", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Foliopalet"].Value));
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Peso", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Peso"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Peso", Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Peso"].Value));

                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Fecha"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Fecha"].Value));

                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Hora"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NinstructivoT", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Ninstructivo"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nnave", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Nnave"].Value));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }

                scope.Complete();
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Guardado con Exito. ", "Guardado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        correo();

        operaciones.numerodecontenedor siguiente = new operaciones.numerodecontenedor();
        this.Close();
        siguiente.Show();

    }
    catch (Exception f)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se an guardado los datos-verifique la conexion a internet", "Error - por favor guarde los datos en excel", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        exportar(dataGridView1);
        correoerror();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

una transacion es lo que necesitas

```
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmm = new SqlCommand();
         SqlTransaction trann = conn.BeginTransaction();
        cmm.Connection = conn;
        cmm.Transaction = trann;
        try
        {
            //for para recorrer el datagrid
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                //recorre la datagrid

                //has un insert en cada recorrido
            }
            //terminas la transaccion
            trann.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //si hay un error
            trann.Rollback();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```